# Consume ASP.NET Web Api 2 (not Core) in Ubuntu for my Angular project

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing local ASP.NET API in my Windows. I want to consume that API in Ubuntu for my Angular project (I explicitly want to use Ubuntu and **NOT** Windows for my Angular project).  
Is there any way I can achieve this?  
I know it can be done if the API is developed in .NET CORE.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the API is developed using .NET Core or older ASP.NET Web API, it will be called in the same way. After all they are just plain HTTP calls.

Comment: So what do I have to do to 'host' the API on Ubuntu?

Comment: you can't host old .net api in linux. You have to port it to .net core and then you can host it on ubuntu behind nginx or apache. there are many articles on it online. alternatively you can host your .net api on iis on a windows server somewhere and then call it from your angular app (but that is probaly more work)

Comment: What do you mean by by host the api? Do you mean you want to move the api in your windows to linux? If so, it is impossible and you need to migrate .net api to .net core api.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it.
Follow the steps below

1. install dotnet core sdk for linux ubuntu
2. install vs code and install extention c# to help you run or use the command line in terminal

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/net-core-command-line-interface

Comment: The links that you gave are for the dotnet Core integration on Linux. I want the integration for web api 2.